# vue-chartjs cannot display the labels and datasets

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, axios, vue-chartjs

I have a problem on my `line-chart`. The data from the api/controller can't transfer on my chart but in response shows all of my data

[image]

As the picture shows, the  `line-chart` was empty but in  the `response` there was a data.

I have a error is said that

> **TypeError:** Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
>       at app.js:86744

i don't know how to fix it please help me. Thanks

---

### Codes

Report.Vue

```
 <div class="container">
       <h1>USAGE</h1>
       <mortalityLineChart :chartdata="datacollection"> </mortalityLineChart>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
     data () {
      return {
          date_input: null,
          number_of_morality: null,
          chicken_age:null,
        datacollection: null
      }
    },
      created () {

          this.fillData()
        },
    mounted () {

        this.fillData()

    },
   methods: {
      fillData () {
          axios.get('/api/report')
          .then(response =>{
              let results = response.data.data

              let dateresult = results.map(a => a.date_input)
              let mortalityresult = results.map(a => a.number_of_morality)
              let chickenageresult = results.map(a => a.chicken_age)

              this.date_input = dateresult
              this.number_of_morality= mortalityresult
              this.chicken_age= chickenageresult    

              this.datacollection = {
                  labels: this.number_of_morality,
                  datasets:[
                      {
                          label:'Mortality',
                          backgroundColor: '#f87979',
                          data:this.date_input
                      }
                  ]
              }
          })
    .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
      },
    }
}
</script>
```

reportMortalityLineChart.js

```
  import {Line} from 'vue-chartjs' // We specify what type of chart we want from vue-chartjs and the mixins module
  export default({
    extends: Line, //We are extending the base chart class as mentioned above
    props: ["mychartData"],
    watch: {
       mychartData: {
        handler: function (val) {
        this._chart.update()
      }, 
        deep: true
      }
    },
    data () {
      return {
        options: { //Chart.js options
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
              },
              gridLines: {
                display: true
              }
            }],
            xAxes: [ {
              gridLines: {
                display: false
              }
            }]
          },
          legend: {
            display: true
          },
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false
        }
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      // this.chartData is created in the mixin
      this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
    }
  })
```

App.js

```
import reportMortalityLineChart from './charts/reportMortalityLineChart'
Vue.component('mortalityLineChart',reportMortalityLineChart);
```

[image]

Preview

```
2017-12-10: 4
2017-12-11: 12
2017-12-12: 17
2017-12-13: 16
2017-12-14: 17
2017-12-15: 10
2017-12-16: 11
2017-12-17: 13
2017-12-18: 6
2017-12-19: 1
2017-12-20: 13
2017-12-21: 16
2017-12-22: 4
2017-12-23: 10
2017-12-24: 10
2017-12-25: 10
2017-12-26: 19
2017-12-27: 5
2017-12-28: 7
2017-12-29: 13
2017-12-30: 13
2017-12-31: 10
2018-01-01: 13
2018-01-02: 23
2018-01-03: 15
2018-01-04: 35
2018-01-05: 61
```

ReportController.php

```
public function index()

{
    $mortality = Mortality::where('cycle_id', 2)
    ->where(['user_id' => Auth::id()])
    ->pluck('number_of_mortality','date_input','chicken_age');

    return response()->json($mortality);
}
```

mortalities table

```
Schema::create('mortalities', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->date('date_input');
    $table->integer('number_of_mortality');
    $table->integer('chicken_age');
    $table->mediumText('cause_of_death')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedInteger('cycle_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id'); 
    $table->timestamps();
```

Comment: `response.data.data` is undefined. Look in dev tools to see the actual response data

Comment: they are null sir. how can i fix it?

Comment: Can you post the full response from the server? On another note unless you have an object key of data on the response you will need to update `let results = response.data.data` to `let results = response.data`

Comment: where can i find the full response ? at the api/ controller? @TimWickstrom.com

Comment: In your picture of chrome devtools you have "reports" highlighted and you have a preview of the response. Simply select all from the Response panel in chrome and paste it in your questions.

Comment: @TimWickstrom.com i edit it sir

Comment: I assume that this is actually an object like it is represented in dev tools... '{'2018-01-05': 61, ....}'

Comment: what im gonna do sir @TimWickstrom.com

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that your API call is async. Thus it may happen, that your chart will be rendered, before your data arrives.

You need to make sure that your data is there.

The easiest approach would be to use a `loaded` state and `v-if` on your chart component.

You can check out the example in the docs: https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#chart-with-api-data

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response that is coming back there are several errors when processing the data.

```
.then(response => {
  // let results = response.data.data <- does not exist
  let results = response.data

  // These keys do not exist on your response date_input, number_of_morality, chicken_age
  // let dateresult = results.map(a => a.date_input)
  // let mortalityresult = results.map(a => a.number_of_morality)
  // let chickenageresult = results.map(a => a.chicken_age)

  // this.date_input = dateresult
  // this.number_of_morality= mortalityresult
  // this.chicken_age= chickenageresult    

  this.datacollection = {
    labels: 'Manually Name Labels', // this.number_of_morality, <- This does not exist on your response
     datasets:[{
       label: 'Mortality',
       backgroundColor: '#f87979',
       data: response.data // this.date_input <- This did not exist on your response
     }]
  }
})
```

This should render something. However, to fix this properly I would need to see what the DB schema looks like for your Mortality model in Laravel.

You could try updating your controller to:

public function index()

```
{
    $mortality = Mortality::select('number_of_mortality','date_input','chicken_age')->where('cycle_id', 2)
    ->where(['user_id' => Auth::id()]);

    return response()->json($mortality);
}
```

But again without seeing the schema, I am not sure that would solve the problem. If you make that change post the updated results of the response in chrome dev tools

Comment: is there a way to get the data from api sir ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not mounting props in reportMortalityLineChart.js
Example:

```
props: {
    // eslint-disable-next-line vue/require-default-prop
    chartData: {
        type: Array,
        required: false
    },
    chartLabels: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
    }
    },

mounted () {
        this.renderChart({
        labels: this.chartLabels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'downloads',
            borderColor: '#249EBF',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: this.chartData
          }
        ]
      }, this.options)
    }
```